# Unable to Update List Collection from View to Controller Method

Tags: c#, razor, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to catch a list of Bullet_Points from view to Edit Method. However i am unable to  save the collection items to database.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Specifications.Count(); i++)
{ 
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Specifications[i].Bullet_Point)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Specifications[i].Bullet_Point)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Specifications[i].Bullet_Point)
}
```

In the `Edit()` method I need to use two `for` loops, with below loops format I don't see the `Bullet_Points` being saved to DB.

1. First `for` loop  which has model count of collection items from View
2. Second `foreach` loop that loops through Query result and binds the Specification Model from View to DB.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form, ProductVm2 VM)
{
    List<Specification> spec = (from sp in db.Specifications
                                where sp.Product_ID == VM.Product.ProductID
                                select sp).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < VM.Specifications.Count(); i++)
    {
        foreach (var sp in spec) {
            sp.Bullet_Point = VM.Specifications[i].Bullet_Point;
        }
        db.savechanges();
    }
```

Comment: Hello @GertArnold ,Sorry for the confusion.
Spec holds the result of resultant query.I want to Iterate through all Bullet_points from Spec and Input values are in VM.Specficiations Object. I have to Iterate through both of them simultaneously to save the Bullet_Points .

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of the `foreach` you assign the value of the current specification `VM.Specifications[i]` to all specification in `spec. The result of this code ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < VM.Specifications.Count(); i++)
{
    foreach (var sp in spec)
    {
        sp.Bullet_Point = VM.Specifications[i].Bullet_Point;
    }
    db.savechanges();
}
```

... is that all specification in `spec` have the value of the last `Bullet_Point` in `VM.Specifications`.

That should probably incur unexpected changes though, so I don't understand why you don't see them.

The correct way to synchronize the view model changes with the database entities is:

```
var pairs = from vmSpec in VM.Specifications
            join dbSpec in spec on vmSpec.SpecificationId equals dbSpec.SpecificationId
            select new { vmSpec, dbSpec };
foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    pair.dbSpec.Bullet_Point = pair.vmSpec.Bullet_Point;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

This pairs the specifications from the view model and the database, assuming that their primary key is `SpecificationId`, and copies the values.